# Where's the 'Where are my tags?' help box?

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

I'm looking for the Where are my tabs? link in the below image.

[image: Where are my tabs?]

So I clicked `Got it` button on the main site:

[image: Got it]

But it seems that I would've liked to see it again anyway.  I was looking for a tab (the `interesting` tab - which, come to find out, is now home), and I wish that you had some sort of help button where I could access that diolog again, even though I clicked the `Got it` button.

This is what my tab bar looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what tag to put for the new question filter - if someone could help with that, it'd be much appreciated.